# From upgrading Magento 2.3 to 2.4 setup upgrade command is struck

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.4, setup-upgrade

I have updated my Magento from version 2.3 to 2.4.
But when i hit bin/magento setup:upgrade it will running from around 1 hr.

When i check show processlist a command is running

```
SELECT `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.`value_id`, `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.`value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE (attribute_id = '123')
```

But it keeps running as i have 60 Million products so how much time it will take to complete setup upgrade.

Any help is appreciated.

Error in log file :

```
[2021-02-09 10:03:53] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["COMPILED_CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
    [2021-02-09 10:04:07] main.ERROR: AMQP topology installation failed: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://127.0.0.1:5672 (Connection refused)
    #0 /var/www/mag/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(219): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->connect()
    #1 /var/www/mag/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(203): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->connect()
    #2 /var/www/mag/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AMQPStreamConnection.php(59): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->__construct('guest', 'guest', '/', false, 'AMQPLAIN', NULL, 'en_US', Object(PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO), 0, 3, 0)
    #3 /var/www/mag/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection->__construct('127.0.0.1', '5672', 'guest', 'guest', '/', false, 'AMQPLAIN', NULL, 'en_US', 3, 3, NULL, false, 0, 0, NULL)
    #4 /var/www/mag/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('PhpAmqpLib\\Conn...', Array)
    #5 /var/www/mag/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('PhpAmqpLib\\Conn...', Array)
    #6 /var/www/mag/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Connection/Factory.php(43): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('PhpAmqpLib\\Conn...', Array)
    #7 /var/www/mag/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(156): Magento\Framework\Amqp\Connection\Factory->create(Object(Magento\Framework\Amqp\Connection\FactoryOptions))
    #8 /var/www/mag/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(169): Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->createConnection()
    #9 /var/www/mag/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/TopologyInstaller.php(86): Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->getChannel()
    #10 /var/www/mag/vendor/magento/module-amqp/Setup/Recurring.php(36): Magento\Framework\Amqp\TopologyInstaller->install()
    #11 /var/www/mag/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(1047): Magento\Amqp\Setup\Recurring->install(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext))
    #12 /var/www/mag/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(840): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), 'schema', Array)
    #13 /var/www/mag/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/UpgradeCommand.php(143): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema(Array)
    #14 /var/www/mag/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UpgradeCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
    #15 /var/www/mag/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
    #16 /var/www/mag/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UpgradeCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
    #17 /var/www/mag/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
    #18 /var/www/mag/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
    #19 /var/www/mag/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
    #20 {main} [] []
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better you execute a command in the background to avoid ssh connection lost issue. To run the command in the background you can add "&" at the end of a command.

Comment: Thanks for your response Yes I have done that and run the command in background.
But the issue is it is still running from around 2 hr and no success.

Comment: Just make sure you check server logs and see if any errors are listed. There are chances process is getting stuck. If not then check the server configuration by hitting htop / top and see if there is memory usage issue.

Comment: I have attached my debug logs in question please check.